# Time Machine: Bulk setting Spotlight attributes failed

Tags: mac-osx, mac, time-machine

I recently had a drive fail in a laptop and after replacing it and restoring a Time Machine backup onto it, any new backups to the same Time Machine backup get this error:

```
May 24 02:10:00 Foobar /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd[9605]: Bulk setting Spotlight attributes failed.
```

How does one fix Spotlight to remove this error?

Answer (score 3):

Rebuilding the Spotlight index [evidently](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=93556) fixes this:

1. System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy: add the affected drive (to stop indexing it)
2. use Terminal.app to delete the affected drive's invisible ".Spotlight-V100" folder*
3. System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy: remove the affected drive (to start indexing it again)

*Example

```
sudo rm -rf /Volumes/YourVolumeNameHere/.Spotlight-V100
```

Remember, be careful when using "rm -rf" to avoid typos, or you could delete the wrong folder!

Comment: An easier method is sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/YourVolumeNameHere to reset Spotlight. This will perform all 3 steps above in one shot. The -i flag will allow you to turn it on and off as well.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Even after running mdutil -E on the volume being backed up, I got this error:

May 26 00:02:22 Foobar /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd[14331]: Bulk setting Spotlight attributes failed.

I also tried running it on the volume that is the Time Machine volume, which is mounted over the network.